# PostgreSQl addition on error on a case expression and from calculating a percentage from a from subquery

Tags: postgresql, subquery, case

I'm writing a postgreSQL query that has to calculate the cost of sheltering animals taking into account, the size, age and location of the animal.

**EDIT**

```
SELECT 
    lower(a.animaltype) as animaltype,
    a.size,
    SUM(a.total) AS total,
    round((SUM(a.total) * 100 / 2263360),2) AS percentage
FROM
(SELECT 
    animals.animaltype,
    CASE 
        WHEN animals.animaltype = 'Dog' AND weight > 30
            THEN 'large'
        WHEN animals.animaltype = 'Dog' AND weight <= 10 
            THEN 'small'
        WHEN animals.animaltype = 'Dog' AND weight BETWEEN  10 AND 30
            THEN 'medium'
        WHEN animals.animaltype = 'Cat' AND weight > 7 
            THEN 'large'
        WHEN animals.animaltype = 'Cat' AND weight <= 5 
            THEN 'small'
        WHEN animals.animaltype = 'Cat' AND weight BETWEEN 5 AND 7 
            THEN 'medium'
        WHEN animals.animaltype = 'Bird' AND weight > 1.1 
            THEN 'large'
        WHEN animals.animaltype = 'Bird' AND weight <= 0.7 
            THEN 'small'
        WHEN animals.animaltype = 'Bird' AND weight BETWEEN 0.7 AND 1.1
            THEN 'medium'
    END AS size,
    SUM
        (CASE
            WHEN animals.animaltype = 'Dog' AND weight > 30
                THEN 175
            WHEN animals.animaltype = 'Dog' AND weight <= 10 
                THEN 125
            WHEN animals.animaltype = 'Dog' AND weight > 10 AND weight <= 30 
                THEN 150
            WHEN animals.animaltype = 'Cat' AND weight > 7 
                THEN 140
            WHEN animals.animaltype = 'Cat' AND weight <= 5 
                THEN 100
            WHEN animals.animaltype = 'Cat' AND weight > 5 AND weight <= 7 
                THEN 120
            WHEN animals.animaltype = 'Bird' AND weight > 1.1 
                THEN 110
            WHEN animals.animaltype = 'Bird' AND weight <= 0.7 
                THEN 70
            WHEN animals.animaltype = 'Bird' AND weight > 0.7 AND weight <= 1.1
                THEN 90
        END)
    +
    SUM(
        CASE 
        WHEN (DATE_PART('YEAR','2021-12-31'::DATE) - DATE_PART('year', animals.birthdate::DATE)) > 4
            THEN 100
        WHEN (DATE_PART('YEAR','2021-12-31'::DATE) - DATE_PART('year', animals.birthdate::DATE)) > 7
            THEN 150
        WHEN (DATE_PART('YEAR','2021-12-31'::DATE) - DATE_PART('year', animals.birthdate::DATE)) > 12
            THEN 200
        WHEN (DATE_PART('YEAR','2021-12-31'::DATE) - DATE_PART('year', animals.birthdate::DATE)) > 15
            THEN 300
        ELSE 
             0
        END)
        
    +
    SUM(
         CASE
            WHEN animals.location = 'San Antonio'
                THEN 120
            WHEN animals.location = 'Dallas'
                THEN 110
            WHEN animals.location = 'Houston'
                THEN 140
            WHEN animals.location = 'Austin'
                THEN 135
            WHEN animals.animaltype = 'Fort Worth'
                THEN 100

        END)
    AS total
FROM animals
LEFT JOIN sponsored_animals ON animals.animalid = sponsored_animals.sponsorid
WHERE sponsorid IS NULL
GROUP BY animals.animaltype, size
ORDER BY animals.animaltype, size DESC) as a
GROUP BY a.animaltype, size
ORDER BY a.animaltype, size DESC
```

The data has been cleanup and the are no null values on the tables, except for those animals without sponsor. therefore the WHERE sponsorid IS NULL clause.

Now, I'm looking for a way get rid of the hard coded 2263360 and simplify the case statements.

Comment: The 2263360 is the sum of the total column, i'm also looking for alternatives to not hard code it.

Comment: You could get rid of those case expressions by putting those classifications into a separate table and join to that. You will probably receive more answers if you provide a little [script](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14) with the table definitions and some sample data.

Comment: Your last case code obviously  is wrong....

Comment: @Mark will update the question to correct some things

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name will do, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the addition, the last case (the location) has no `else` case. If an animal is in a different city than the listed ones, this case leads to a `null` value, the entire addition is null for this record and this record is therefore ignored from the `sum`

Comment: the data base has been clean up, those are the only values on the location column